# Eclipse CDT Console does not link to code for compilation errors

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse for my C++ project under Linux. When I get compilation errors I can see them in the Console window.

I am currently manually navigating to the file and line number to fix errors. Is is possible to get Eclipse to provide links to the correct file and line number?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Would you like to help others by telling us how?

Answer (score 4):

You may need to configure Eclipse to parse the errors emitted by your compiler to allow it to extract the file name and line number.

The CDT FAQ has some more info: [How do I add an Error Parser (or The project seems to build file, but doesn't parse my error output what can I do?)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_add_an_Error_Parser_.28or_The_project_seems_to_build_file.2C_but_doesn.27t_parse_my_error_output_what_can_I_do.3F.29)

Note Eclipse CDT should be set up for GCC out of the box. Just noticed you mention you're looking at the Console View. Have you tried looking at the Problem View - this should show a list of Errors & Warnings, where you can double-click each item to jump the file and line in question.

Comment: For me, I went to Propject Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Error Parsers, and checked "GNU gcc/g++ Error Parser" (change in toolchain was the cause of it being unchecked).  Obviously it'll be different for other toolchains, but that was it for me.  Can't do without this functionality.

Comment: @radsdau This comment should be the answer. Stupid thing but I didn't get that I needed to **double-click**  on the line mentioned to jump to the code. There's no mouse-over underline (like with Eclipse python module for ex.)